# Read version from global location

Tags: java, pom.xml

I got 4 pom file in project, I would like to keep all my pom versions in ope property file and would like to read from that file. I have no clue how to achieve that.
I tried these...
I created pom.properties file under resources and trying to read properties like this.. Unfortunately my code is not working. Please help me......

```
<resources>
 <resource>
   <directory>src/main/resources/pom.properties</directory>
 </resource>
</resources>

enter code here
```

Thanks in advance
Ganta

Answer (score 1):

Use a "parent" pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</parent>
```

And in the parent pom you can define properties like this:

```
<properties>
    <camel.version>2.12.0.redhat-610379</camel.version>
    <cxf.version>2.7.0.redhat-610379</cxf.version>
    <activemq.version>5.9.0.redhat-610379</activemq.version>
</properties>
```

And finally you can reference the properties via syntax like this: `${camel.version}`